# Is A still an M matrix after one gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Supose there is a matrix A which is an M-matrix. Then A(1) is formed after one step of gaussian elimination such that:

A(1) = M(1)*A.

How can I prove that A(1) is still an M matrix?

Comment: What's an M-matrix?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix

Comment: Basically all the off diagonal elements are zero or negative and all diagonal elements are positive.

Comment: I see. Funny I've never heard that term before...

Comment: Would you happen to know the answer to my question now that you know what it is?

Comment: No, I'm sorry...